# Python: regular expressions word match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've written this small little script but I can't get the re.search function to work properly. I'm trying to match only the exact word (joke), but the elif statement keeps returning the print because it finds joke (from joker) in the sentence variable. Is there any way to make it do a count on the number of letters in the word joke so it's only true if joke is a standalone word?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

sentence = 'The substantial treat shouts with the jokers'
find_emergency = re.search( r'emergency', sentence, re.M|re.I)
find_joke = re.search( r'joke', sentence, re.M|re.I)

if find_emergency :
   print 'Do you want to set this email as urgent?'
elif find_joke :  
  print "Do you want to mark this email as non-urgent?"
else :
   print "Sorry, we couldn\'t find what you were looking for ;("
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find_joke = re.search( r'\bjoke\b', sentence, re.M|re.I)
```

use `\b` or the `word boundary` for that.

Comment: Thank you @vks - that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word boundary method as suggested by vks.

Or you could perform a basic search using 'in' keyword.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

sentence = 'The substantial treat shouts with the jokers'

if 'emergency' in sentence :
   print 'Do you want to set this email as urgent?'
elif 'joke' in sentence :  
  print "Do you want to mark this email as non-urgent?"
else :
   print "Sorry, we couldn\'t find what you were looking for ;("
```

Comment: still it would match joker `i.e)"joke" in "i am a joker" True`